# python tuple assignment if a tuple is mutable

Tags: python, tuples

I am new to python. Tuples are said to be immutable but why is that we can do something like this. i.e. to concatenate and change the original value

```
a=(1,2,3)
>>> a
(1, 2, 3)
>>> b=(4,5,6)
>>> b
(4, 5, 6)
>>> a=a+b
>>> a
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

in this case aren't we changing the values in the tuple a?

Comment: no. you are assigning a new tuple to `a`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you're making a new tuple. Consider.

```
>>> a = (1, 2, 3)
>>> a1 = a
```

Now `a1` and `a` are the same tuple. Not just similar looking ones; they're *the same*. Then

```
>>> b = (4, 5, 6)
>>> a = a + b
```

Now `a` is `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)`. Did we change the first tuple we made? Let's ask Python.

```
>>> a
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
>>> a1
(1, 2, 3)
```

Nope, the original tuple stayed the same.

This distinction is important. You made a new tuple and happened to give it the same name. That means that, if you were writing a complicated program with a huge object hierarchy, the change you just made to `a` wouldn't break any of the other objects or code that *depended* on the previous value of `a`. It only broke your particular `a` variable that you control. On the other hand, if we had a list `a = [1, 2, 3]` and started appending to it, then any other object who happened to hold a reference to that list is now going to see the changes, which results in messy errors at a distance.

Comment: Note that `list`s (which are mutable) would behave identically in this case, since it's always doing concatenation and reassignment. If `a = a + b` were changed to `a += b` though, behaviors would diverge; `tuple`s don't implement mutating concatenation, so `a += b` continues to behave mostly like `a = a + b`, but a `list` would be modified in place, which would affect the observed value in `a1`.